# Reduce margins around app widget in Android 4.0 and above

Tags: android, android-appwidget, margins

Since space is at a premium in an app widget, particularly when sized at 4x1 or 3x1, it's a bit frustrating that Android 4.0+ enforces a blank margin around the widget.  See the [Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html) and [Adding Margins](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AddingMargins).

How does one reduce the size of the automatic margin for 4.0 and above?  I know that Android would frown upon it, but I know that it can be done because I have some widgets that don't have any margin around them, on my 4.1 device.  Or is that because the app would have been built against a lower API (compileSdkVersion)?  The compileSdkVersion for my app is 21.

Thanks for any insight on this issue.